# Blob images will not display in Chrome if revokeObjectURL is invoked

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, cgi, blob

-----update------

I commented out the `window.URL.revokeObjectURL( imgSrc );` and now the call works in all browsers. It seems like the url was being revoked too soon in Chrome. I would still be very curious to know why this is, and to know if there are any problems in anyone's opinion with the way I am handling revoking the URLs now. I now revoke the last URL as the next one is loaded with `if (imgSrc) {window.URL.revokeObjectURL( imgSrc );}` (imgSrc is now a global variable).

---

I have a web site which uses AJAX to call a CGI script, which outputs image/jpeg data, and the blob response is then set as the src of an image on the page using the createObjectURL function. At present it works in all browsers but Chrome.

In all other browsers the image is displayed, but in Chrome I get the message: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` followed by a url prefixed by `blob:`.

I have tried using webkitURL instead, but this gives me the same error followed by `webkitURL is deprecated`.

This is the code of my AJAX call:

```
var filepath = "/babelia.cgi";
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onload = function(oEvent) {
if (imgSrc) {window.URL.revokeObjectURL( imgSrc );}
        var blob = xmlhttp.response;
        if (endless) {
        imgSrc = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
        document.getElementById("palette").src = imgSrc;
        // window.URL.revokeObjectURL( imgSrc );
        babel();
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("POST",filepath,true);
xmlhttp.responseType = "blob";
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var info = "location=" + postdata;
if (!landscape) {info += "&flip=portrait";}
xmlhttp.send(info);
```

You can see the website here: https://babelia.libraryofbabel.info/slideshow.html

Comment: I noticed that in Chrome the first colon in the URL which is created is replaced by `%3A`, whereas this does not happen in the other browsers. I tried adding `imgSrc = imgSrc.replace(/https%3A\/\//,"https://");`, to place the colon back in the url, but the images still would not appear, and I received the same error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had some issues understanding blobs as well, here are my 2 cents.

1. I recommend using https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js for abstracting away browser differences when working with blobs.
2. When debugging chrome check out chrome://blob-internals/ for details. With the current version (47.0.2526.106) it shows the urls and the associated data or references to local files for those urls.
3. As soon as you revoke the url you basically tell the browser that you no longer need the data, which is good if you want to free memory, but bad if you still have references pointing to that url (e.g. an img tag).

*Side note: reading your question made me solve of my own problem which was that I was seeing 404s in chrome after revoking because I still had a reference to a revoked url on an img tag.*